# Ace editor "define is not defined"

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm trying to add the [ace editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) to my app. I downloaded it from github, dropped the "ace/lib/ace" directory into my app's directory, included:

```
<script src="ace/lib/ace/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>"
```

in my body tag and:

```
editor = ace.edit "editor"
```

in my script tag. I've tried to load the page in Chrome and Firefox and I get "define is not defined" in ace.js:46. The line in ace.js is:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
```

Does anyone know why ace is expecting the define() function to exist and why it's not finding it? Here's my source:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="editor">some text</div>
    <script src="ace/lib/ace/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem... Did you ever get it figured out?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I decided it wasn't worth my time. Good luck.

Comment: It turned out, I just needed to download one of the packages (the zip file) from the Git page, as opposed to using the cloned repo (they packaged up the code a bit differently in the zip file). So, if you ever decide to give it a shot again, it's a pretty cool editor.

Comment: same problem here where is the zip download?

Comment: Incase anyone is still looking for it, the link is here: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds

Just click ZIP to download the folder.

Comment: I think this is correct link: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/releases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have the source, then it is pretty easy to do still. Just go in the directory where you copied all the ace source.

Then, do:

```
npm install
node Makefile.dryice.js
```

See the wiki for additional details
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Building-ace

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to actually build the code and your comment reminded me to do it. Oops. ☺

Answer (score 8):

I hacked it by putting `window.define = ace.define;` in my DOMload handler.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because the [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) JavaScript library has not been included in your page.

To fix this either use an ace build or include RequireJS in your page.

If you choose to include RequireJS your html fragment will look something like this:

```
<!-- Editor will go here -->
<div id="editor"></div>

<!-- Load RequireJS -->
<script src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize ace -->
<script>

    // Tell RequireJS where ace is located
    require.config({
        paths: {
            'ace': 'lib/ace'
        }
    });

    // Load the ace module
    require(['ace/ace'], function(ace) {
        // Set up the editor
        var editor = ace.edit('editor');
        editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
        editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
        // etc...
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In React, if at all you are importing anything from ace-builds, your import order matters.

It should be like this

```
import AceEditor from 'react-ace';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json';
```

Not like this

```
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json';
import AceEditor from 'react-ace';
```

Answer (score -4):

Alternatively you can use a cdn

- http://cdnjs.com/libraries/ace/
- http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!ace

And replace

```
<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

With something like

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem in any way